# Creating multiple directories with fish shell

Tags: linux, terminal, fish

Using bash I can easily create a number of directories at once with this syntax: `mkdir test{1..10}`

However, with the fish shell this does not work.

How can I create multiple directories at once with the fish shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish does not support the `{x..y}` range expansion syntax.

Instead just use `seq`, like

```
mkdir test(seq 1 10)
```