# fish is treating bash script as a fish script

Tags: fish

I have a bash script like bellow:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create-multiple-chapters {1..5}
# create-multiple-chapters {1,2,5}

for i in $*; do
    mkdir chapter${i}
    touch chapter${i}/init.adoc
done
```

It create multiple directories with file. I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62267218/1772898) that fish does not support the {x..y} range expansion syntax. However, this is a bash script. Still when I run this script from fish shell like `create-multiple-chapters {1..5}`, it only create one directory named `chapter{1..5}`. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you think the argument `{1..5}` is expanded by this line of your script:

```
for i in $*; do
```

In fact, that is an incorrect assumption. When your inteactive shell is Bash, and you type `create-multiple-chapters {1..5}` at the command line, it is the interactive shell itself that does the expansion, and turns the command line into `create-multiple-chapters 1 2 3 4 5`. The Bash script then processes each of these five arguments in the loop.

Fish doesn't do this expansion. Instead, if you are running fish, you need to use the `seq` command to do the expansion and pass the expanded arguments to your Bash script.

Comment: You mean I have to do something like `create-multiple-chapters (seq 1 5)`?

Comment: I don't know the fish shell, but if that expands properly, then that's what you have to do. Try `echo (seq 1 5)` - if it prints `1 2 3 4 5` then it should work.